# How to remove libc6-dev-amd64 in Ubuntu 13.10 64bit

Tags: ubuntu

I need to remove libc6-dev-amd64 to install libc6-dev-i386, but I cannot remove it.
Does anyone knows how to that?

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried? Why you cannot do it? I mean, did that report an error or something?

Did you tried:

<strike>$ sudo apt-get remove libc6-dev-amd64</strike>

```
    $ sudo dpkg -r --force-depends libc6-i386
```

then install the other one.

Comment: Unpacking libc6-dev-i386 (from .../libc6-dev-i386_2.17-93ubuntu4_amd64.deb) ...
 dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6-dev-i386_2.17-93ubuntu4_amd64.deb (--unpack):
  trying to overwrite '/usr/include/sys/timerfd.h', which is also in package libc6-dev-amd64 2.17-93ubuntu4
DuplicateSignature: package:libc6-dev-i386:(not installed):trying to overwrite '/usr/include/sys/timerfd.h', which is also in package libc6-dev-amd64 2.17-93ubuntu4
ErrorMessage: trying to overwrite '/usr/include/sys/timerfd.h', which is also in package libc6-dev-amd64 2.17-93ubuntu4

Comment: Let me ask you why you want to do that :D
Anyway you can check this: 
[link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2073770&page=2)

Comment: Thanks ElTête! The link you gave me, it works!!!  sudo dpkg -r --force-depends libc6-i386